# Is there a term for variables that have min and max values?

Tags: terminology

Is there a mathematical term for variables that have min and max values where it can only have values between both?

Take speedometers for example; they display how fast the car can go, meaning how high their speed can go up to. And since they cannot be lower than 0, it means the speed variable of a car has constraints of min and max values. Is there a way to express this variable with some sort of mathematical term instead of simply showcasing a speedometer in this case? Sorry if this is a bad example.

In other words, is there a term that can be used instead of saying **a variable with min and max values**?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you want the notion of being '[bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set)', which applies to a set, potentially of numbers.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean?  Are you talking about a variable that has constraints?  Numbers themselves have only one value, of course, so I can't quite put my arms around the situation you are describing.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Exactly! What I meant was a variable, not a number, my bad. A variable that has constraints of min and max values, where it cannot be higher and lower than those values.

Comment: Perhaps we can help if you [edit] the question to provide a sample paragraph in which you want to use the term you are asking for. That will tell us more than your trying to describe it to us.

Comment: @EthanBolker Sure thing. I edited my post, please review it again.

Comment: I don't think there is such a term. If there were, it would be so unfamiliar that you could not rely on your reader to know it. Just say what you mean in words: the speedometer can show any nonnegative value up to $150$km/hour.

Comment: I think the notion of being "bounded" @MoonLightSyzygy said is the closest thing I am searching for. Thanks, people.

Answer (score 0):

See [Big Oh notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition). I think this is what you are looking for. Or even the concept of [Bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_function) functions.

Comment: I don't think so. Big-O is for long term behavior and boundedness is about the values in the codomain, not the domain.

Comment: @EthanBolker Can't a variable be represented as a map? If someone tells that a variable have min and max, I first think that there is $C>0$ bounding the values that this variable can take.

Comment: Yes, you can bound a variable. But when you talk about a bounded function you are bounding the range.